# Change animation character in mixamo fbx animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling, mixamo

I have a mixamo based animation with a specific character in fbx format. This animation includes some custom made objects as well, that were later added on top of the original mixamo animation. I am wondering if there is a simple way to use this fbx file to add more mixamo animations to that character and if there is a way to change the character itself to another fuse generated character, using the exact same animation as the one on the fbx file. Is there an easy way to do that without being a 3d animator ? (which i am not :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Import the character as `humanoid` in fbx settings inside unity.
[image]

You can then, retarget animations to multiple characters by using the same `animation controller` to multiple character having different `avatar`.
There's a step by step guide here. Have a look at this link:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Retargeting.html 
Hope this helps.